# Websphere: inject a ALTER SESSION command to datasource connection

Tags: configuration, websphere, datasource

In our development machines we are using Websphere Apllication Server Liberty accessing a Oracle database. To configure case-insensitive or accent-insensitive sort we configure the Datasource session of server.xml file as:

```
<dataSource id="MyDS" jndiName="jdbc/MyDS" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <jdbcDriver javax.sql.DataSource="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" libraryRef="OracleJDBC"/>
    <connectionManager maxPoolSize="10" minPoolSize="2"/>
    <properties.oracle URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521:database" password="..." user="..." />

    <onConnect>ALTER SESSION SET nls_sort = binary_ai</onConnect>
    <onConnect>ALTER SESSION SET nls_comp = linguistic</onConnect>

</dataSource>
```

In Production machines we use Websphere Apllication Server. To configure the dataSource configurations it is needed go to the administrative console,  Resources > JDBC > Data sources. Although I was able to connect to the Data source, I could not find a way to inject those ALTER SESSION commands above.

I suspect that I need to add a new property in Custom properties page. I tried add a property **onConnect** with both commands (separated with ';'), but it did not work. Even googling, I could not find a satisfactory answer.

Does someone have any idea how to make this configuration?

Thanks,

Rafael Afonso

Answer (score 1):

To do that on WebSphere traditional go to `WebSphere Application Server data source properties` under `Additional Properties` and check `validate new connections`.  Provide your SQL statements in the `Validation by SQL query` section.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that Alex gave is the simplest way to do this in WebSphere Application Server traditional.  For completeness, I wanted to point out that there is one other way of doing this in WebSphere Application Server traditional, which is by defining a [custom data store helper](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tdat_cusdatstore.html) and overriding the [doConnectionSetup](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/rsadapter/GenericDataStoreHelper.html#doConnectionSetup(java.sql.Connection)) method to perform the desired SQL command(s).  This approach might be necessary if unable to specify multiple SQL commands within the `Validation by SQL query` attribute.  In that case, leave `Validation by SQL query` blank and do not select either of the `validate new connections` or  `Validate existing pooled connections` options.

Answer (score -1):

Alex:

I tried your suggestion. In imagem below, I added this command:

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_sort = binary_ai; ALTER SESSION SET nls_comp = linguistic; commit;
```

[image: Data source configuration]

However, when I runned my application, it made no difference. 
Besides, as we can see in the image, the `Validation by SQL query` section is deprecated.

Comment: You should check `validate new connections` rather than `Validate existing pooled connections`.